# Decomposition of conditional expectations (economics)

Tags: regression, econometrics, simulation

I would really appreciate it if someone could clarify the following rather simple approach to determine if a given factor has any impact on a conditional expectation.

**Classic methodology:** Evaluate $\mathbb E_0[x_T|y_T<10]$ by jointly simulating 2 time series $\{(x_t,y_t)\}_{t=1:T}$, where $x_t>0$.

**Question to answer:** How large is the impact of the values $z_T \leq 12$ of another given variable $z$ on the value of $\mathbb E_0[x_T|y_T<10]$?

**Proposed approach:** jointly simulate 3 time series $\{(x_t,y_t,z_t)\}_{t=1:T}$ and use the following well-known representation
\begin{equation}
\mathbb E_0[x_T|y_T<10] = \mathbb E_0 [x_T|y_T<10,z_T \leq 12]\mathbb P(z_T \leq 12|y_T<10) \\
\hspace{68pt} +\mathbb E_0[x_T|y_T<10,z_T>12] \mathbb P(z_T>12|y_T<10)
\end{equation}

**Claim:** if the value of the term $\mathbb E_0[x_T|y_T<10,z_T \leq 12]\mathbb P(z_T \leq 12|y_T<10)$ turns out to be *much* larger than the value of the other term, then the impact of $z_T \leq 12$ (on $\mathbb E_0[x_T|y_T<10]$) is larger than that of $z_T > 12$.

Is this a right claim? If not, then what claim would be the right one (based on the proposed approach)?

Thank you!

Comment: Well if you want the impact of z conditional on it occurring then you wouldn't want to weight by it happening. If you just want the overall impact then what you're doing is reasonable.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It seems a rather simple approach, but does it have a name?